# Change Google Service Account picture

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

As I am using service account to share Google Drive documents, it would be nice to get in invitation email a company picture instead of the silhouette.

Is it possible to change somehow Google Service account picture?

I tried using the Google Admin SDK, but I get the following error:

```
404 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey"
 }
}
```

I tried this through the API explorer:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/update

EDIT, the userKey is the email address of the account. In the service account case it is in the format:

```
account-name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your service account to use [delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) to impersonate and use a separate Google Apps account email address to do the document sharing. Set the photo in that Google Apps account.